# Android. Espresso: How check uppercase of TextView?

Tags: android-espresso

Android 3.1.2, Gradle 4.4, Java 1.8, Espresso 3.0.1.

Here snippet of my xml layout:

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginTextView"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_login_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="@{ () -> presenter.doLogin()}"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Here result:
[image]

As you can see text in this **TextView** show in uppercase. Nice.
No I want to write Espresso test that check is this **textView** is on **uppercase**.
So here my Espresso instrumentation test:

```
@Test
    public void loginTextViewUppercase() {
        onView(withId(R.id.loginTextView)).check(matches(withUppercaseText(R.string.login)));
}


public static Matcher<View> withUppercaseText(final int resourceId) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
            private String resourceName = null;
            private String expectedText = null;

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
                if (null == expectedText) {
                    try {
                        expectedText = textView.getResources().getString(resourceId).toUpperCase();
                        resourceName = textView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignored) {
                        /* view could be from a context unaware of the resource id. */
                    }
                }
                CharSequence actualText = textView.getText();
                if (null != expectedText && null != actualText) {
                         return expectedText.equals(actualText.toString());
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with uppercase string from resource id: ");
                description.appendValue(resourceId);
                if (null != resourceName) {
                    description.appendText("[");
                    description.appendText(resourceName);
                    description.appendText("]");
                }
                if (null != expectedText) {
                    description.appendText(" value: ");
                    description.appendText(expectedText);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

But when I start test **loginTextViewUppercase** I get error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with uppercase string from resource id: <2131624014>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with uppercase string from resource id: <2131624014>[login] value: LOGIN
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296429, res-name=loginTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=765, height=180, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@7f5fced, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=158.0, y=1283.0, text=Login, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:90)
```

Comment: Did you check that your TextView actually contains all the capital letters? Your matcher looks more or less fine.

Comment: Yes, When I start app the login is in uppercase.

Comment: I update my post and put my screenshot.

Comment: Could you put a debug breakpoint in if (null != expectedText && null != actualText) {  and check expectedText and actualText values?

Comment: expectedText = LOGIN , actualText = Login

Comment: Exactly, which means that android:textAllCaps is not working as you expect. I suggest creating a separate TextView class that sets all chars to the uppercase (please see my answer below)

Comment: This is bug of Android? Why flag android:textAllCaps not work correctly? But on screenshot it show as uppercase. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve the transformation method from the `TextView` itself to check that it's textAllCaps. In this case, you don't need to add any modifications to the prod code:

```
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            if (null == expectedText) {
                try {
                    expectedText = textView.getResources().getString(resourceId).toUpperCase();
                    resourceName = textView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignored) {
                    /* view could be from a context unaware of the resource id. */
                }
            }
            String actualText = textView.getText().toString();
            if (null != expectedText) {
                     TransformationMethod currentMethod = textView.getTransformationMethod();
                     //if the transformation is AllCapsTransformationMethod then it means that the text is uppercase
                     return expectedText.equalsIgnoreCase(actualText) && currentMethod != null && AllCapsTransformationMethod.class.getClass().isInstance(currentMethod.getClass());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it's work. Second approach. Here one more solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769514/espresso-check-if-text-is-in-upper-case/49770700?noredirect=1#comment88643886_49770700

Answer (score 0):

its solved for me
loginTextView.setText(strings.toUpperCase());

Comment: Where you put this code? I wan't to set uppercase programmatically. Only via xml.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.